# How to use ICU without setting ICU_DATA directory

Tags: c++, icu

I'm trying to use ICU4C on windows. I copied the 2 dlls into the executable directory and a ICU data file. According to what I read in the documentation, I should not need to set a specific data directory (http://userguide.icu-project.org/icudata), but my unit-tests run only when I set the ICU_DATA environment variable. Otherwise U_FILE_ACCESS_ERROR is returned on initialization or creation of converters. Can anyone tell me how to "install" this correctly so that I don't need to set the path?

Comment: Have you tried using a data DLL instead of a .dat file?

Comment: did you ever figure this out, i think it cannot actually read it without u_setDataDirectory

Comment: @gagolews - Do you know how to use the data DLL on Windows?

Answer (score 0):

is the data dll 'big' or 'small'? ( kilobytes or megabytes ). Maybe it is the stub data dll and the full one is hiding.

Comment: I know this is very old now, but I'm running into something very similar.  Any idea where the data DLL is in a standard MSVC build?  The nearest I can find based on "icudt" and file size is "icudt##l_dat.obj" which is 24MB for me (ICU57).

Comment: @codesniffer hi! the DLL should be under `bin` or `bin64` if the build succeeded.